# Python pandas timeseries resample giving unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas

The data here is for a bank account with a running balance. I want to resample the data to only use the end of day balance, so the last value given for a day. There can be multiple data points for a day, representing multiple transactions.

```
In [1]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: print "Pandas version", pd.__version__
Pandas version 0.12.0

In [5]: print "Numpy version", np.__version__
Numpy version 1.7.1

In [6]: data_string = StringIO(""""Date","Balance"
   ...: "08/09/2013","1000"
   ...: "08/09/2013","950"
   ...: "08/09/2013","930"
   ...: "08/06/2013","910"
   ...: "08/02/2013","900"
   ...: "08/01/2013","88"
   ...: "08/01/2013","87"
   ...: """)

In [7]: ts = pd.read_csv(data_string, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)

In [8]: print ts
            Balance
Date               
2013-08-09     1000
2013-08-09      950
2013-08-09      930
2013-08-06      910
2013-08-02      900
2013-08-01       88
2013-08-01       87
```

I expect "2013-08-09" to be 1000, but definitely not the 'middle' number 950.

```
In [10]: ts.Balance.resample('D', how='last')
Out[10]: 
Date
2013-08-01     88
2013-08-02    900
2013-08-03    NaN
2013-08-04    NaN
2013-08-05    NaN
2013-08-06    910
2013-08-07    NaN
2013-08-08    NaN
2013-08-09    950
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

I expect "2013-08-09" to be 930, or "2013-08-01" to be 88.

```
In [12]: ts.Balance.resample('D', how='first')
Out[12]: 
Date
2013-08-01      87
2013-08-02     900
2013-08-03     NaN
2013-08-04     NaN
2013-08-05     NaN
2013-08-06     910
2013-08-07     NaN
2013-08-08     NaN
2013-08-09    1000
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Am I missing something here? Does resampling with 'first' and 'last' not work the way I'm expecting it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to resample your data Pandas first have to sort it. So if you load your data and sort it by index you get the following thing:

```
>>> pd.read_csv(data_string, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0).sort_index()
            Balance
Date               
2013-08-01       87
2013-08-01       88
2013-08-02      900
2013-08-06      910
2013-08-09     1000
2013-08-09      930
2013-08-09      950
```

Which explains why you got the results you got. @Jeff explained why the order is "arbitrary" and according to your comment the solution is to use `mergesort` algorithm on the data before the operations...

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(data_string, parse_dates=[0],
                     index_col=0).sort_index(kind='mergesort')
>>> df.Balance.resample('D',how='last')
2013-08-01      88
2013-08-02     900
2013-08-03     NaN
2013-08-04     NaN
2013-08-05     NaN
2013-08-06     910
2013-08-07     NaN
2013-08-08     NaN
2013-08-09    1000
>>> df.Balance.resample('D', how='first')
2013-08-01     87
2013-08-02    900
2013-08-03    NaN
2013-08-04    NaN
2013-08-05    NaN
2013-08-06    910
2013-08-07    NaN
2013-08-08    NaN
2013-08-09    930
```

Comment: a sort on duplicates is arbitrary (e.g. no guarantees from merge or quick sort), IIRC

Comment: @Jeff I thought that was the case. But it would be a really nice feature if Pandas could recognise (on read) that the data is already sorted (like in this case) and just use that sort order. :) Yes I know... It's an "I wan't a pony" request :)

Comment: pls put a request on github; I don't know how tricky this is (its in the group index calcs)

Comment: This answer lead me to the solution, which is to use .sort_index(kind='heapsort') because heapsort is a stable sort algorithm, meaning that the original order will be preserved. Can you edit your answer to include this?

Comment: @Jeff is this really a stabile solution? If it is then there is no need for the github issue.

Comment: there is a ``sort`` keyword to ``groupby`` to handle this case! (but not too resample)

Comment: According to this wikipedia page, heapsort is NOT stable, so the correct answer is to use kind='mergesort' which is stable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability

Answer (score 0):

The problem is since your dates are dups there can effectively be an arbitrary order; ordering with dups is not guaranteed.

```
In [24]: ts.Balance.resample('D',how='last')
Out[24]: 
Date
2013-08-01     87
2013-08-02    900
2013-08-03    NaN
2013-08-04    NaN
2013-08-05    NaN
2013-08-06    910
2013-08-07    NaN
2013-08-08    NaN
2013-08-09    930
Freq: D, dtype: float64

In [25]: ts.Balance.order().resample('D',how='last')
Out[25]: 
Date
2013-08-01      88
2013-08-02     900
2013-08-03     NaN
2013-08-04     NaN
2013-08-05     NaN
2013-08-06     910
2013-08-07     NaN
2013-08-08     NaN
2013-08-09    1000
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Easiest way is to `sort` the data, but it is not clear what the ordering actually is (e.g. you need an exogenous parameter here to decide it).

pass `sort=False` to a groupby (you can't do this with resample though)

```
In [29]: ts.groupby(ts.index,sort=False).last().reindex(date_range(ts.index.min(),ts.index.max()))
Out[29]: 
            Balance
2013-08-01       87
2013-08-02      900
2013-08-03      NaN
2013-08-04      NaN
2013-08-05      NaN
2013-08-06      910
2013-08-07      NaN
2013-08-08      NaN
2013-08-09      930
```

You can do it this way to get exactly what you are after

```
In [52]: df = DataFrame(ts.values,index=ts.index,columns=['values']).reset_index()

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
                 Date  values
0 2013-08-09 00:00:00    1000
1 2013-08-09 00:00:00     950
2 2013-08-09 00:00:00     930
3 2013-08-06 00:00:00     910
4 2013-08-02 00:00:00     900
5 2013-08-01 00:00:00      88
6 2013-08-01 00:00:00      87

In [54]: df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]['values']).reindex(date_range(ts.index.min(),ts.index.max()))

Out[54]: 
2013-08-01     87
2013-08-02    900
2013-08-03    NaN
2013-08-04    NaN
2013-08-05    NaN
2013-08-06    910
2013-08-07    NaN
2013-08-08    NaN
2013-08-09    930
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```